# Open Editor From Command Line and Fetch Input

Tags: ruby, command-line, rubygems

I'm currently working on a feature for [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org), a Ruby gem. There's an existing command that accepts a number of options. I'd like to add an extra option that enables the user to enter a custom message by opening the default text editor and, when the user saves and quits the editor, the message is fed to the command that was executed.

What I want to replicate is how you can add `-m` to the `git commit` command to have you enter a commit message. I have little experience with creating command line tools so any help is much appreciated.

The goal is to execute a specific command `command --message`, open the editor, have the user enter a custom message, and execute the command with the custom message being one of the arguments stored in `argv`.

Comment: The `interactive_editor` gem seems related to what you try to achieve. I did not check the source, but there might be ideas to pick there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common workflow is:

- the caller application creates a temporary file;
- determines the default editor (for Debian-based it would be `/usr/bin/editor`, for other linuces — the content of shell variable `$EDITOR`, etc);
- runs a shell command in a subshell with [`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-system) (not with backticks!);
- waits for it to exit;
- determines the exit code, and skips following if it is not `0`;
- reads the content of temporary file, created in step 1 and removes this file.

In ruby that would be like:

```
▶ f = Tempfile.new 'cocoapods'
#⇒ #<File:/tmp/am/cocoapods20151120-6901-u2lubx>
-rw------- 1 am am 0 nov 20 15:03 /tmp/am/cocoapods20151120-6901-u2lubx
▶ path = f.path
#⇒ "/tmp/am/cocoapods20151120-6901-u2lubx"
▶ f.puts 'This content is already presented in file'
#⇒ nil
▶ f.close # HERE MUST BE ENSURE BLOCK, BUT FOR THE SAKE OF AN EXAMPLE...
#⇒ nil
▶ system "editor #{path}"
#⇒ Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

If you are testing this in console, just type anything, followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>. In real life there will be normal `vim` (or what the default editor is) opened.

```
▶ File.read path
#⇒ "GGGGGGGGGThis content is already presented in file\n"
```

All together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'tempfile'

f = Tempfile.new 'cocoapods'
path = f.path
f.puts 'This content is already presented in file'
f.close # HERE MUST BE ENSURE BLOCK, BUT FOR THE SAKE OF AN EXAMPLE...
system "editor #{path}"
puts File.read path
```

Comment: That's a great start. The problem I'm running into is getting the contents of the file before the Ruby script exits. The Ruby script exits when the editor is opened. I was hoping/expecting that it would continue its execution the moment the editor is closed. You write `File.read path`. Where do you read the contents of the temporary file?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I messed things up: to invoke an editor in the same context (in a subshell,) one should use [`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-system) rather that backticks. I updated an answer with the code of the whole script for your convenience.